# How to add directories/subdirectories (by wildcard) to be searched by Maxima's "load" function

Tags: maxima

I know how to add some directories to the default value of `file_search_maxima`; for example as mentioned in the documentation, the below setting appends two additional directories to the default value of file_search_maxima:

`file_search_maxima: append (file_search_maxima,["/usr/local/foo/###.mac", "/usr/local/bar/###.mac"])$`

Is it achievable to append all subdirectories of a given directories to the value of `file_search_maxima`?

e.g., something like below, which appends all subdirectories by "wildcard" (unfortunately it does not work):

```
file_search_maxima: append (file_search_maxima,["/usr/local/###/###.mac"])$
```

Is this achievable at all?

**Motivation**: a specific directory is soon getting crowded after putting Maxima files in it. Hence, it would be a good idea to put the Maxima files in subdirectories/subfolders. But, in order to be able to load the files, it will be necessary to add the subdirectories one by one. It would be great if "load" function could search within all subdirectories of a given "safe" directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is possible, but you'll have to do some work to get what you want.  First use `directory("/usr/local/**/")`.  This will produce a list of all the subdirectories of "/usr/local/".  For each element in the list, append "###.mac".  Finally, prepend this to `file_search_maxima`.

However, in git HEAD, it will be easier.  The pattern to use is different.  You'll just need to add "/usr/local/**/*.mac".  Then maxima will automatically search all the subdirectories of "/usr/local/" to find a mac file.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, based on your suggestion `for i:1 thru length(directory("/user/local/**/")) do (file_search_maxima: append (file_search_maxima,[concat(directory("/user/local/**/")[i],"###.{mac,mc,max}")]));` can do the job.

Comment: If one is just interested to add the immediate subdirectories (and not sub-subdirectories, etc,) `for i:1 thru length(directory("/user/local/*/")) do (file_search_maxima: append (file_search_maxima,[concat(directory("/user/local/*/")[i],"###.{mac,mc,max}")]));` can do the job.

Comment: Just to be clear, being able to add search directories by wildcard pattern will be in the next release of Maxima, which will be 5.48.

Comment: Also note that in the next release, maxima will only recognize ".mac" files for maxima-supplied files.  But maxima will recognize ".mac" and ".wxm" from your user directory (".maxima").  Of course, you can add whatever extensions you like to file_search_maxima.